# LESS CSS - Different elements in a function

Tags: css, function, stylesheet, less, mixins

I use LESS CSS. My code looks like this.

**Repeatable pattern**

Do you see the pattern in my code? The only thing that differs the two is the padding value and the class name.

**Question**

Is it possible in LESS CSS to make a function / mixin of a **block** like this with many different elements?

**LESS CSS**

```
&.pad-10 > [class*='cols-'] {
    background: #ccc;
    padding: 10px;

    &:first-child {
        padding-left: 0;
    }

    &:last-child {
        padding-right: 0;
    }
}

&.pad-20 > [class*='cols-'] {
    background: #ccc;
    padding: 20px;

    &:first-child {
        padding-left: 0;
    }

    &:last-child {
        padding-right: 0;
    }
}
```

**Mixin suggestion**

```
    do_padding( $value ) {
        &.pad-@value > [class*='cols-'] {
            background: #ccc;
            padding: @valuepx;

        &:first-child {
            padding-left: 0;
        }

        &:last-child {
            padding-right: 0;
        }
    }

    do_padding( 10 );
    do_padding( 20 );
```

I know that my exact problem can be solved in other ways without LESS CSS, but I have this problem from time to time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you just need to set up a proper counting and looping structure in LESS. Here's how:

**LESS**

```
.do_padding(@startValue, @increment) {

  .loop(@value) when (@value > 0) {
    //set top amount
    &.pad-@{value} > [class*='cols-'] {
      background: #ccc;
      padding: @value * 1px;

      &:first-child {
        padding-left: 0;
      }

      &:last-child {
        padding-right: 0;
      }
    }
    // next iteration
    .loop(@value - @increment);
  }

  // end the loop when index is 0 or less
  .loop(@value) when not (@value > 0) {}

  //start the loop
  .loop(@startValue);
}
```

**Use it**

```
.myClass {
   .do_padding(30, 10);
}
```

**CSS Output**

```
.myClass.pad-30 > [class*='cols-'] {
  background: #ccc;
  padding: 30px;
}
.myClass.pad-30 > [class*='cols-']:first-child {
  padding-left: 0;
}
.myClass.pad-30 > [class*='cols-']:last-child {
  padding-right: 0;
}
.myClass.pad-20 > [class*='cols-'] {
  background: #ccc;
  padding: 20px;
}
.myClass.pad-20 > [class*='cols-']:first-child {
  padding-left: 0;
}
.myClass.pad-20 > [class*='cols-']:last-child {
  padding-right: 0;
}
.myClass.pad-10 > [class*='cols-'] {
  background: #ccc;
  padding: 10px;
}
.myClass.pad-10 > [class*='cols-']:first-child {
  padding-left: 0;
}
.myClass.pad-10 > [class*='cols-']:last-child {
  padding-right: 0;
}
```